# how to combine plsql select statement with different column and different where condition

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

Sorry for having dummy table names but I want to combine these two queries in one single select view. I have tried UNION and CROSS JOIN operator but I am finding issues in both. Both Qyuery sharing the same tables so i gave table names same only alias are different.
As there are so many columns in each table and the query was also a bit long so could not write the whole query but my query looks like this only
Can anyone please suggest ways to resolve this?

```
select 
    a.col1,
    b.col2,
    c.col3,
    d.col4,
    e,col5
from 
    table1 a, table2 b, table3 c, table4 d, table5 e
where 
    a.col1 = b.col2 
and b.col2 = e.col3(+)
and d.col5 = b.col6
and a.col7 = 'Active';

select 
    a.col5,
    b.col6,
    c.col7
from
    table1 a, table2 b,table5 c 
where 
    b.col2 = c.col3
    and a.col7 = 'Active';
```

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` - if it satisfies your needs - would work; columns that are "missing" should be replaced by a `NULL` *placeholder*. Something like this:

```
select 
    a.col1,
    b.col2,
    c.col3,
    d.col4,
    e,col5
from 
    table1 a, table2 b, table3 c, table4 d, table5 e
where 
    a.col1 = b.col2 
and b.col2 = e.col3(+)
and d.col5 = b.col6
and a.col7 = 'Active'
union 
select 
    a.col5,
    b.col6,
    c.col7,
    null,                             --> this
    null                              --> and this
from
    table1 a, table2 b,table5 c 
where 
    b.col2 = c.col3
    and a.col7 = 'Active';
```

Also, consider

- using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` (might be faster as `UNION` removes duplicates)
- `CAST` `NULL`s to appropriate datatype, e.g. `cast(null as varchar2(10))` because - when using `UNION` - selects have to match in number of columns, while columns must match in datatypes. Oracle will implicitly try to convert `NULL` to appropriate datatype, but - why not taking control over it?

Comment: My original query tables having 60-70 columns each and my 1st query having 27 different columns than 2nd query having 20 column ... So it will be easy to do that?

Comment: Type faster, I presume.

Comment: Sorry for slow typing !

Comment: My where condition is different in both queries do you have any idea to tackle this? please help!